# setImage method changes UIBarButtonItem width, even if image size doesn't change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add a "bookmark" button to my navigation bar as a rightBarButtonItem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add bookmark button
    UIBarButtonItem *bookmarkBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(bookmark:)];
    [bookmarkBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyBookmark.png"]];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bookmarkBarButton];
    bookmarkBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0.4 blue:0.4 alpha:0.9f];
    b_bookmarked = false;
}

// Will call this method when the bookmark button is pressed
- (IBAction)bookmark:(id)sender
{
    // Toggle color of bookmark icon on button
    if ( (b_bookmarked = !b_bookmarked) )
    {
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueBookmark.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyBookmark.png"]];
    }

    // Save bookmark

}
```

both greyBookmark.png and blueBookmark.png have 10x26 size. Button looks narrowed when view appears. But when I click this button, button gets wider, image still changes though. 
Width changes when setImage method is called in bookmark: method (gets back to default size). I tried to explicitly set the width by calling [navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setWidth:]  -  doesn't help either. Before doing that, width property was set to 0 and button should have resize depending on its image size, according to documentation.

I want the rightBarButtonItem to have a const width.
Is there a reason why it gets wider after the second call to setImage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyBookmark.png"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 3.0, 70,30);
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(BookmarkButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbutton;
```

Put this method under `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)BookmarkButtonPressed

{

      //Do ur work here for Button Action

}
```

Comment: Oh I see. So you can create a UIButton and use it as a BarButton. The width of button doesn't change anymore, that's good. But to change the image, I had to cast barbuttonItem's customView to UIButton and call setImageNamed: forState:

Comment: Sorry, can't vote up, not enough rep.
Vote up my question, and I will have enough reputation (15) to vote up your answer.